# Can anyone suggest how can i get all product data if products are more than 50k?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have create script which create product feed csv file and it’s working properly with 10k products.

Now admin have added 50k products in admin panel so now product feed file is created but not contains all product data.

**Can anyone suggest how can i get all product data if products are more than 50k?**

I have also try to export all product using data profile from admin panel but it’s also not working.

I have also try with sql query to get data from tables but it’s also break after some data.

Comment: I can give you one suggection for your script you should create a magento cron. so by every day cron will run and your product will be imported. 
so if you will do this with cron then you can export unlimited products.

Comment: Thank You for reply, my script is already executing using cron but still it’s not working.

Comment: Then  cron must be terminated with some reason try to find out some system log or log for cron so you will get idea what exactly problem is.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but we have no idea how to help you with your question. There's no way for us to know what you're even trying to do. What is the code you're using to export products? Are you using Magento's API?